# developing a osx deamon that runs before user login using xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, daemon

Hi I am trying to develop a daemon using objective-C/xcode.

I am new to mac world and can I get an idea of what project template to choose in xcode and how to do it.

Can I get a simple and basic daemon sample source code ?

Answer (score 4):

The "Command Line Tool" project is sufficient to start writing a daemon.  There are no special build requirements as such, it just depends on what you want the daemon to do.

The way to write a Mac OS X daemon is very much like the way you would approach it on a regular Unix system.  Accordingly, there are a few things to keep in mind:

- **non-interactive**: you don't get direct input from the user, but you also have to use something like `syslogd` for output, as the process is not attached to a terminal
- **environment**: don't assume it has a particular current directory, path, default permissions, or any other environmental settings - explicitly set these up
- **security**: ensure the daemon has the barest minimum privileges required to perform its function, and no more (this is a huge topic in itself)
- **signals**: you will need to trap and respond to certain signals, as these are typically used for process control (eg. `SIGHUP` forces the daemon to reload its config file)

There are some [good writeup on Unix daemons](http://www.enderunix.org/docs/eng/daemon.php) if you go looking.  The Stephens book on Unix is always good, too.

There is some [Mac specific information on daemons](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Articles/DesigningDaemons.html) to consider, mainly regarding integrating with `launchd`.

A typical daemon will do something like the following:

- double-fork, to detach from the parent process
- set up process group and effective UID
- install signal handlers
- set file permissions umask
- change directory to a work directory
- read configuration file
- open sockets, etc
- go into an infinite loop to service requests

There is a [simple daemon example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_%28computer_software%29) in the Wikipedia article too.

Comment: To clarify, this will be a `LaunchDaemon`, and not a `LaunchAgent`.  `LaunchDaemon`s run as root (which is needed to run before login), and `LaunchAgent`s run as the user.