# LION OS: Run Mac app in the background

Tags: osx-lion

I am new Mac programming but having enough experience on iOS development. I am developing a Mac application. I want my application to be running in the background of the system always and do some kind of syncing, like Dropbox does. I want to know how can i run my app in the background always as soon as my app is launched and do some process from my app in the background in certain interval.

Please advise!

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can, Mac is a full fledged OS.  [developing a osx deamon that runs before user login using xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1530785/developing-a-osx-deamon-that-runs-before-user-login-using-xcode)

Comment: Could you give me the tutorial link or something, using which i can follow-up, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Mac OS X is just UNIX at its heart.  Anything you can do on a *NIX system, you can do on OS X.  See: [Interprocess communication.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interprocess_communication)
You really need to understand the concept of IPC before you can tackle how to accomplish it with a specific OS.

Comment: Could you give me the tutorial link or something, using which i can follow-up, thank you.