# Mac Service (equivalent to Windows Service)

Tags: macos, service, daemon

I want to create a Mac Service (equivalent to Windows Service) which should keep on running in the background and from my client application (GUI) I want to pass some parameters to it.

Can you please give me some sample/tutorial which explains this clearly.

Thanks

Comment: Look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1530785/developing-a-osx-deamon-that-runs-before-u

Comment: thanks benjamin that was helpful. I would appreciate if you can tell me where I can find an example code

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of a service on the Mac that I just made to get you started:

### Creating a ISO Image of a Folder

[Matt Berther](https://matt.berther.io/2008/12/14/creating-iso-images-from-a-folder-in-osx/) submitted this handy Terminal script to create ISO images from folders in OS X. I know I'll forget how to do this soon enough, and so I made a handy Service for the same.

**Step 1:** 
Open Automator < Create a new ***"Service"***

**Step 2:** 
Search for the Action ***"Run Shell Script"*** and drag it onto the main panel on the right.

**Step 3:**

1. Set the "Service receives selected" dropdown to "Folders"
2. Set the "in application" dropdown to "Finder"
3. Set the "Shell" dropdown to "/usr/bin/python"
4. Set the "Pass input as" dropdown to "as arguments"

**Step 4:** 
In the script itself, replace the existing code with the following:

```
import sys
from subprocess import call

call('hdiutil makehybrid -o {0}.iso {0} -iso -joliet'.format(sys.argv[1]), shell=True)
```

Save the Service as "Create ISO". Quit Automator.

**Step 5:**

1. ***Access Using Mouse:*** When you right click on a folder in Finder, you should now see the new service in the menu. If you have a large amount of services you've created (like me) then it'll be nested in the Services submenu of the right click.
2. ***Access Using Keyboard Shortcut:*** 
   If this is a service you use really often you can assign a keyboard shortcut to it:

   - Open System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts
   - Click on Services on the Left Menu
   - Find the Service you've just created > Add a Key Pair to create a shortcut.

**Step 6 (Optional): Debugging PBS** 
[Credit: [A Really Old Macworld Hint]](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20100805100621261)

Sometimes Services in Snow Leopard stop working for no apparent reason. The menu is missing from the contextual menu items when you do a right-click, and the Services menu in the menu bar shows only 'Building...' Other times, there may be more than one entry for the same service. These problems can always (in my experience) be corrected without logging out or rebooting.

The technique is simple. Run the following command in a Terminal window:

```
/System/Library/CoreServices/pbs
```

Your Services should now be working.

> [crarko @Macworld adds: A more little explanation is good for this one; the pbs
>   utility is a debugging tool (follow the link, and scroll down to
>   'Testing' at the bottom) related to the Pasteboard Service in Cocoa.
>   Running it will force a rescan of Services which is why the above will
>   work. It's been mentioned in a previous hint back in 2004, so it's
>   been around for a while. I doubt anyone noticed if there was a problem
>   with Services prior to 10.6. Apple mentions that it could change or be
>   removed at some point, so don't depend on it indefinitely.]